# PHP Request for posting Form to Iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

firstly any help is much appreciated. In very new to php but love wordpress!

I have searched the web everywhere for a simple solution to my issue but struggled to find a working answer.

In short, i have a form on homepage that allows entry of arrival date, departure date and number of guests. i need the form to post these parameters to an booking system provided by a third party BUT hosted on my website via an iframe - but another page, not the homepage where the form is - MUST EMPHASIZE THAT).

Anyway, i'm almost there! but I am struggling to work out the PHP to display a string of php request functions.

Firstly, my current implementation is showing this code on the page source code (NOTE: iframe delibrately spelt wrong to embed here)

`<iBrame name="testframe" src="https://externalurl?siteId=KAYSCLAY&request_locale=en&chainAction=newAvailabilitySearch&29/11/201330/11/201312"></ibrame>`

The url aspect of the iframe needs to be as follows:

`https://externalurl?siteId=KAYSCLAY&request_locale=en&chainAction=newAvailabilitySearch&arrival=09%2F07%2F2013&departure=10%2F07%2F2013&numberOfPersons=1&numberOfChildren=0`

So I have two problems. I am only showing two dates combined together in my iframe src string, these need to be seperated, and I am also missing two paramters for some uknown reason - number of people parameters.

Below is my code hardcoded on the iframe php page (html/php) and also my form. Any thoughts, help is much appreciated.

`<ibrame name="testframe" src="https://externalurl?siteId=KAYSCLAY&request_locale=en&chainAction=newAvailabilitySearch<?php echo ''.$_REQUEST['arrival'].$_REQUEST['departure'].$_REQUEST['numberOfPersons'].$_REQUEST['numberOfChildren']?>"></ibrame>`

`

```
<div class="FormField Arrival">
    <label for="arrival">Arrival Date</label> <input id="arrival" name="arrival" type="text" /></div>
<div class="FormField Departure">
    <label for="departure">Departure Date</label> <input id="departure" name="departure" type="text" /></div>
<div class="FormField NumberOfPersons">
    <label for="numberOfPersons">Adults</label> <select id="numberOfPersons" name="numberOfPersons"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div>
<div class="FormField NumberOfChildren">
    <label for="numberOfChildren">Children</label> <select id="numberOfChildren" name="numberOfChildren"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div>

<div class="FormField Submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Book now" /></div>
      </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
function validate(theform) {
if (theform.domain.value == "") { alert("No domain entered"); return false; }
return true;
}
</script>`
```

Comment: `<form target="iframe1" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$adnn = array('arrival', 'departure', 'numberOfPersons', 'numberOfChildred');
foreach($adnn as $v){
  $r[] = "&$v=".rawurlencode($_GET[$v]);
}
echo "<iframe name='testframe' src='https://externalurl?siteId=KAYSCLAY&request_locale=en&chainAction=newAvailabilitySearch$r[0]$r[1]$r[2]$r[3]'></iframe>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This does work. I also managed to get another method up and running too - I was expecting an email to let me know i had a response on this site! my bad.

Comment: However, neither take it to consideration formatting the date (arrivals and departure) before outputting it again.

Comment: Firiefox, ie etc work fine, but tables, mobiles arew outputting date format as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Wrong format and also using hyphens now! ahh!

Comment: Some Browsers will reorder `$_GET` URLs. You can use the `$r` array increments elsewhere in your code.

Comment: anyone have any futher assistance on this?

Comment: struggling on two things,

Comment: the date is outputting as '14%2F12%2F13' but i actually need it to be '14%2F12%2F2013'  - the longer month format.

Comment: Obviously that has to do with the `$_GET` information that is sent to your PHP by either the user that puts it into your `<input type='text' name='arrival' id='arrival' />', or `<input type='text' name='departure' id='departure' />`, or through a preloaded URL. This really is another question.